# Visualizing multivariate data using aesthetic mapping in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a geom_point plot using ggplot2 with multivariate data and I am running into issues color coding the data and also visually plotting it. I have shared my data below: I am interested in Effort (X axis) versus hairchange (y-axis) and color code the data by hairtype (type of hair loss: diffuse, frontal/temporal, and/or vertex) However, the nature of the survey is multivariate where patients were able to endorse multiple hair loss types (HairType 1,2,and/or 3). Code for the first 20 participants is below:

```
Figure3Data = structure(list(MonthsMassage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
MinutesPerDayMassage = c("0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"11-20 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily"), Minutes = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), hairchange = c(-1, -1, 0, 
-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1), 
HairType1 = c("Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
"Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
"other", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
"Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
"Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
"Templefrontal"), HairType2 = c("other", "other", "other", 
"other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "Vertexthinning", 
"Vertexthinning", "other", "Vertexthinning", "other", "other", 
"Vertexthinning", "other", "Vertexthinning", "Vertexthinning", 
"other"), HairType3 = c("other", "Diffusethinning", "other", 
"Diffusethinning", "other", "other", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", 
"Diffusethinning", "other", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", 
"other", "other", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "other", 
"Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning"), 
Effort = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), EffortGroup = c("<5", "<5", "<5", 
"<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", 
"<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Due to the fact that patients endorsed hairtypes belonging to multiple columns I am not able to separate the data visually using the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Effort, y=hairchange, color  = hairtype????)+geom_point()
```

If the data was somehow in 1 column showing hair loss it would be easy to visualize:

[image: geom_point 1 column]

Therefore, I was wondering if there was a way organize the data to allow for visualization and color coding of the 3 hair loss types? I have tried reshape2 and melt without any luck. I want to avoid creating a 4th category of “multiple types reported” since this blinds many on the insights I want to make.

Alternatively, suggestions for alternative approaches to graphing this data (density/line plot) would be greatly appreciated. One idea I had is to have four separate line graphs – one per hair loss type (i.e., average, diffuse, vertex, temporal) – with the x-axis as Effort and the y-axis as the average perceived-hair change.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and seems to be more in the "advice" area than about a specific programming question. You are in a better position than anyone here to know what kind of figure would show your conclusions best. So you will probably get better advice if you can make your question specific about how to achieve that.     That said, you might try using `color  = interaction(HairType1, HairType2, HairType3)` to show the different combinations in one chart, or look at the `UpSetR` package as a way of showing univariate data across combinations of features.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am specifically looking to make a `geom_dotplot` showing Effort (a axis) and hair change (y axis) color coded by the three hairloss types. I want to show only the 3 distinct hairloss types visually with 3 colors, regardless if data points overlap (i.e, patient endorsed 2 or more hair loss types - just plot it 2x). I also want to eliminate the "other" hairloss type in each columns 5-7. For the first 20 data points I provided, I want to plot 19 data points for Temporal on top of 6 Vertex data points and 12 Diffuse data points. Each a different color. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the following code snippet:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(MonthsMassage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      MinutesPerDayMassage = c("0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
                                               "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
                                               "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
                                               "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
                                               "11-20 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily", 
                                               "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
                                               "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
                                               "0-10 minutes daily"),
                      Minutes = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
                      hairchange = c(-1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1), 
                      HairType1 = c("Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
                                      "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
                                      "other", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
                                      "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
                                      "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
                                      "Templefrontal"),
                      HairType2 = c("other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "other",
                                    "other", "Vertexthinning", "Vertexthinning", "other", "Vertexthinning",
                                    "other", "other", "Vertexthinning", "other", "Vertexthinning", 
                                    "Vertexthinning", "other"),
                      HairType3 = c("other", "Diffusethinning", "other", "Diffusethinning", "other", "other",
                                    "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "other", 
                                    "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "other", "other", "Diffusethinning", 
                                    "Diffusethinning", "other", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning"), 
                      Effort = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), 
                      EffortGroup = c("<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", 
                                      "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5"))
```

You could create a brand new column combining the three hairtypes as simply paste the 5th, 6th and 7th columns together as a new 'combinedHair' column:

```
dt[, CombinedHair:=do.call(paste0,.SD), .SDcols=c(5,6,7)]
```

If you want to plot the data of this data table, it has overplotting, so I would suggest the `geom_jitter()` function:

```
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x=Effort, y=hairchange, color  = CombinedHair))+geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1)
```

If you want better class names, then you can replace the 'default's with empty quotation marks I think.

[image: Plot generated with the code above]

Comment: Thank you! is it possible,however, to create a brand new column that combines the three hairtypes into a Combined hair column but doesn't create new categories (i.e., DiffusexVertex thinning) but only has the original 3. I only want to plot the three distinct hair types (Diffuse, Vertex, Temporal) in 3 colors regardless if data points overlap (i.e., if a patient reports Diffuse and Temporal thinning then two data points are plotted in the same location corresponding to the colors of diffuse and temporal. The code above creates a total of 6 hairloss types. Also how do i eliminate the "other"

Comment: @jbearazesh you can eliminate "other"s just like `dt[dt == 'other'] <- ''`. So you select the cells with the value "other" in them, and replace the values with an empty char ''.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that moves the location into it's own variable (not shown here, but you could map it to facets, or point shape, or some other aesthetic if you wanted to), and then plots the color based on the hairtype, removing "other" hairtypes.

```
library(tidyverse)
Figure3Data_long <- Figure3Data %>%
  gather(location, hairtype, HairType1:HairType3) %>%
  filter(hairtype != "other")

ggplot(Figure3Data_long,
       aes(Effort, hairchange, color = hairtype)) +
  # geom_point() +  
  geom_jitter(width = 0.03, height = 0.01)  # illustrative to show overplots
```

[image]